# How should I do to have a fast emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

Sorry my bad English.

I installed Android Studio 2.0, and I have problems with the emulator.

When I launch the emulator that I used with Android Studio 1.5.1 appears the windows [A], the emulator is slow
as before but the app works; when in fact I launch a NEW emulator appears to me the window [B], and then appears
no emulator.

WHAT IS HAXM?

How should I do to have a fast emulator?
Regards.

Comment: Images:

[A] https://www.dropbox.com/s/vs5scdlfoawve98/HAXM%20A.png?dl=0

[B] https://www.dropbox.com/s/px5amdbnqtbwsvm/HAXM%20B.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion makes a pretty good emulator in my opinion. It's way faster than the android studio emulator. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Well don't worry about it. first of all **HAXM** is a software which makes hardware based virtualization. in simple words it uses your hardware resources to make a virtual device like android device you are talking about.

if you don't have a HAXM software download it and install it and then check if virtualization is enabled or supported in your BIOS settings. press esc or delete whatever the key is to go into bios settings of your computer while computer first starts up. very similar like below.
[image]

go to **Advanced Bios Features**

then look for virtualization if its disabled then enable it otherwise its good to go.
[image]

so if you are done with HAXM lets come back to the android studio and start android device manager or **AVD** and follow the tutorial from android developers page its already answered [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html). And android emulators are fast now from *android studio 2.0* don't worry about it otherwise you can download [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) or [bluestack](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

happy coding.